# Having an issue with Flash Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Wondering if you guys can help me. I've used online tutorials to create the following.

I am working on a small flash project and I've hit a wall. Basically, I've got 3 scenes. A home page, and 2 games. My home page and one of the games are programmed on the timeline within an actions layer. The third game is applied to a Main.as. The problem is that I want to apply a button called home to the Flappy game, but since I've used the .as file for this code, I'm unsure how to do it.

Basically, my question is "How do I add a button to the "Flappy" Scene? Each time i try to do it and run a test, It's playing the Flappy Game over the Scene 1.

Main.as  ("Flappy" Scene3)

```
    package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.Event; //used for ENTER_FRAME event
    //import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{

        //These are all of the constants used.

        const gravity:Number = 1.5;            //gravity of the game. How fast ball falls
        const dist_btw_obstacles:Number = 300; //distance between two obstacles
        const ob_speed:Number = 8;             //speed of the obstacle
        const jump_force:Number = 15;          //force with which it jumps

        //variables
        var player:Player = new Player();      
        var lastob:Obstacle = new Obstacle();  //varible to store the last obstacle in the obstacle array
        var obstacles:Array = new Array();     //an array to store all the obstacles
        var yspeed:Number = 0;                 //A variable representing the vertical speed of the bird
        var score:Number = 0;                  //A variable representing the score

        public function Main(){
            init();
        }

        function init():void {
            //initialize all the variables
            player = new Player();
            lastob = new Obstacle();
            obstacles = new Array();
            yspeed = 0;
            score = 0;

            //add player to center of the stage the stage
            player.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            player.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            addChild(player);

            //create 3 obstacles ()
            createObstacle();
            createObstacle();
            createObstacle();

            //Add EnterFrame EventListeners (which is called every frame) and KeyBoard EventListeners
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrameHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, key_up);
        }

        private function key_up(event:KeyboardEvent){
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
                //If space is pressed then make the bird
                yspeed = -jump_force;
            }
        }

        function restart(){
            if(contains(player))
                removeChild(player);
                for(var i:int = 0; i < obstacles.length; ++i){
                    if(contains(obstacles[i]) && obstacles[i] != null)
                    removeChild(obstacles[i]);
                    obstacles[i] = null;
                }
                obstacles.slice(0);
                init();
        }

        function onEnterFrameHandler(event:Event){
            //update player
            yspeed += gravity;
            player.y += yspeed;

            //restart if the player touches the ground
            if(player.y + player.height/2 > stage.stageHeight){
                restart();
            }

            //Don't allow the sheep to go above the screen
            if(player.y - player.height/2 < 0){
                player.y = player.height/2;
            }

            //update obstacles
            for(var i:int = 0;i<obstacles.length;++i){
                updateObstacle(i);
            }

            //display the score
            scoretxt.text = String(score);
        }

        //This functions update the obstacle
        function updateObstacle(i:int){
            var ob:Obstacle = obstacles[i];

            if(ob == null)
            return;
            ob.x -= ob_speed;

            if(ob.x < -ob.width){
                //if an obstacle reaches left of the stage then change its position to the back of the last obstacle
                changeObstacle(ob);
            }

            //If the bird hits an obstacle then restart the game
            if(ob.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2,player.y + player.height/2,true)
               || ob.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2,player.y - player.height/2,true)
               || ob.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2,player.y + player.height/2,true)
               || ob.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2,player.y - player.height/2,true)){
                restart();
            }

            //If the bird got through the obstacle without hitting it then increase the score
            if((player.x - player.width/2 > ob.x + ob.width/2) && !ob.covered){
                ++score;
                ob.covered = true;
            }
        }

        //This function changes the position of the obstacle such that it will be the last obstacle and it also randomizes its y position
        function changeObstacle(ob:Obstacle){
            ob.x = lastob.x + dist_btw_obstacles;
            ob.y = 100+Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-200);
            lastob = ob;
            ob.covered = false;
        }

        //this function creates an obstacle
        function createObstacle(){
            var ob:Obstacle = new Obstacle();
            if(lastob.x == 0)
            ob.x = 800;
            else
            ob.x = lastob.x + dist_btw_obstacles;
            ob.y = 100+Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-200);
            addChild(ob);
            obstacles.push(ob);
            lastob = ob;
        }  
    }
 }
```

Here is the code for my main page called "Scenery" (Scene 1) which is in an actions layer of timeline.

```
        stop();

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    sun1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cloudy);

    function cloudy (e:MouseEvent){
        cloud1.x = cloud1.x + 10;
        cloud2.x = cloud2.x - 10;

    }

    pong_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        gotoAndStop(1, "SheepyPong");
    }

    dodge_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler3);
    function mouseDownHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void {
        gotoAndStop(1, "Flappy");
    }

This is my code for a very simple "SheepyPong" (Scene2) game which is linked to from front page:

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;

var velocityX:Number = 5;
var velocityY:Number = 5;

movieClip_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        movieClip_1.y -= 5;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        movieClip_1.y += 5;
    }
    sheep.x += velocityX;
    sheep.y += velocityY;

    if(sheep.y + sheep.height/2 > stage.stageHeight || sheep.y - sheep.height/2 < 0){
        velocityY *= -1
    }

    if(sheep.hitTestObject(AI) || sheep.hitTestObject(movieClip_1)){
        velocityX *= -1;
    }

    if (sheep.x < 0) {
        score2.text = (int(score2.text) +1).toString();
        sheep.x = 275;
        sheep.y = 200;
        velocityX *= -1;
    }

    if (sheep.x > stage.stageWidth) {
        score1.text = (int(score1.text) +1).toString();
        sheep.x = 275;
        sheep.y = 200;
        velocityX *= -1;
    }


    AI.y = sheep.y;
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }

    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }

    }//end of switch
}//end of function 

home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler1);
function mouseDownHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scenery");
}
```

I'm also getting this error in output when I run it. It's not actually affecting the outpu

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main/onEnterFrameHandler()[/Users/mynamehere/Documents/Game/Main.as:91]

```
//This is line 91 in the Main.as file:
scoretxt.text = String(score);
```

Comment: it says `scoretext` cannot be found , did you declare the name correctly ?

Comment: Yes. it is named scoretxt :) That's why I'm confused about the error.

I actually got the button working. The problem I'm having now is that it's playing main.as over the first two scenes when I use the button. Haha

Comment: try placing this `trace(score)` in line 90 or something and let me know whether the error shows in this line

Comment: I put it at 89 and that moved the scoretxt down to 92. This is being returned now: 

0
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Main/onEnterFrameHandler()[/Users/name/Documents/Game/Main.as:92]

Comment: I think I might be able to live with the error for now since it's otherwise working. That text frame is incrementing by one each time I get a score as it should do. What I am alot more worried about is Main.as applying itself to Frames 1 and 2 if I add a home button to Frame 3. (In my case Scenes 1 and 2 since each Scene only has 1 frame). I'm not experienced with Flash at all, so I've probably done something I shouldn't have.

Comment: The thing you shouldn't have done is use Scenes. It breaks things every time. I don't know of anyone who has been using AS2 or 3 for more than a month that still uses Scenes to organize content or code. If you must code on the timeline, there are people that can help (I'm not one of them since I don't use the Timeline). It's much easier to just put all your main menu stuff inside a Sprite container and your Flappy content in another container and add and remove those containers as needed in the first frame of the main timeline. Then you don't lose variable references etc.

Comment: Thanks Neal. Yeah, wish I had known when i started this :) It probably would have saved me many hours of Frustration hehe. Many many years ago, I learned the basics of Flash and they taught us using scenes. It's changed a lot since then. I don't even know which AS I was using to be honest.